# Weird-looking France after OSM import with osm2pgsql

Tags: postgis, polygon-creation, osm2pgsql

After importing `france-latest.osm` from Geofabrik, using osm2pgsql, it seems that the polygon attributed to Metropolitan France (osm_id = 1403916) is a bit odd:

[image: France polygon in QGis]

I'm far to be a geography expert, but I think that the shape is a bit off here.

Is there something I missed?

Thanks

Comment: What is osm_id of that polygon?

Comment: The osm_id is 1403916 (edited)

Comment: Yes, it looks odd when compared with http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/1403916#map=5/46.710/2.900 I am sorry but I can't say why.

Comment: Can you add the full osm2pgsql command line used?